# firebase close called on closed connection

Tags: java, client, firebase

When accessing firebase via the Java client, I'm seeing the message "close called on closed connection".  This is the exact printout I'm seeing when running the following code.  It looks like the auth is working, but I'm curious where this message is coming from.

generateToken()...
 generateToken() end
 close called on closed connection
 Succeeded!

using firebase-client-1.0.7.jar

```
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.firebase.security.token.TokenGenerator;
import com.firebase.security.token.TokenOptions;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class TestInput {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_URL).auth(generateToken(), new Firebase.AuthListener() {

        public void onAuthError(FirebaseError error) {
            System.out.println(" Failed! " + error.getMessage());
        }

        public void onAuthSuccess(Object authData) {
            System.out.println("Succeeded!");
        }

        public void onAuthRevoked(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            System.out.println("Authentication status was cancelled! " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        }

    });


}

private static String generateToken() {

    System.out.println("generateToken()...");

    JSONObject arbitraryPayload = new JSONObject();

    TokenGenerator tokenGenerator = new TokenGenerator(Constants.FIREBASE_SECRET);
    TokenOptions to = new TokenOptions();
    to.setAdmin(true);
    to.setDebug(false);
    String token = tokenGenerator.createToken(arbitraryPayload, to);

    System.out.println("generateToken() end");
    return token;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is from the Firebase SDK, if you upgrade to the latest JAR, it will not appear anymore.